# Custom Auto-Generated Sequences with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I had to generate a auto generated value based on input 
I tried some logic in which it changes from units place

The input and output is as follows.

```
Input        Output
-----------------------
"A0000"        "A0001"
"A9999"        "B0001"
"Z9999"        "AA000"
"AA999"        "AB999"
"ZZZZ9"        "ZZZZZ"
```

Comment: what are the rules for this output?

Comment: It is used to generate id there is a input followed by output

Comment: can you purify your question and state what are the problems ?

Comment: I guess last two lines should read "AA999"-"AB000" and "ZZZZY"-"ZZZZZ"?

Comment: yes the output is the value you expected @okrumnow